# PHP session collision

Tags: session, php

I was wondering if anyone has come across the problem where users will open up multiple tabs or windows of your web application and then discover that parts of the application are using the other window/tab's data (I'm sure you have).

Obviously, this is occurring because the tabs/windows are sharing the same PHP session ID and so when you call up a record and store it's ID in the session, the second window's call replaces the ID of the first window and can cause all types of headaches.

What solutions have you come up with to avoid this problem?  Putting the ID in a hidden field?  Using session name rewriting at the top of your script (which I'd like to avoid)? I'm curious to the solutions you have come up with for this problem. Is my design junk and I shouldn't do it like that? How do the big players out there solve this problem?

same question I pose here ...

```
    <?php
      session_start();
    // some code ... 
    // if user successful login 
    $_SESSION['user_id'] = $users_id 
    // we redirect user to member page
    if (isset($_SESSION['user_id']){
    header("Location:members.php");
    }else{
    header("Location:login.php");
    }

    ?>
members.php
<?php
 session_start();
if (!isset($_SESSION['user_id']){

    header("Location:login.php");
    }

echo "welcom user : {$_SESSION['user_id']}";
?>
```

Comment: A log out method would be useful, or if a user is attempting to log in then session_destroy() any existing session

Comment: a new browser page, means a new tab on same browser ??

Comment: May be you cant add a expiry time for the session. literally speaking your behaviour is not a abnormal behaviour, this is how its working as of now across all major sites:) either you want to remind the user abt the idle process on your page and ask him to logout or by default add a expire time of 5 min to expire the page.

Comment: @Err same or another browser

Comment: @Anigel yes but is new user login the same session varibale will be created and the user 1 will still logged

Comment: How can another user login, if someone already logged in ??
Aren't you checking if logged in then no login prompt etc..?

Comment: @ErrHunter: either new tab or new browser window, there will be a seperate instance of the specified browser running on the machine.

Comment: New tab and separate instance of the browser are different things. a session in one tab is shared with the same site in another tab, a completely separate instance of the browser running under a different identity will not see the other session. Which is it?

Answer (score 0):

```
if(isset($_SESSION['user_id']) && !empty($_SESSION['user_id']))
{
 echo "welcom user : {$_SESSION['user_id']}";
}
else
{
 header("Location:login.php");
}
```

Comment: Np its will not work coz user 2 logged in and the same session variable has been created , user 1 will also still logged in but his id will change to the user 2

Comment: Let me get this straight, you want two different users on the same browser on different tabs to be able to be logged into two different accounts at the same time?

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately in PHP there is no efficient solution to generate multiple session across multiple windows tabs.

As a solution to this you can use javascript HTML5 SessionStorage (window.sessionStorage)

You will generate a random id and save in session Storage per Browser Tab. Then each browser tab has his own Id.